# Laravel Sanctum & NuxtJS SPA not creating csrf cookie in the browser

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I have a backend API in Laravel with Sanctum, and separate repository SPA in NuxtJS

I am trying to authenticate my SPA with Sanctum. I am trying to get the CSRF cookie in the browser as per Sanctum documentation.

The problem is when I call the CSRF token endpoint provided by Sanctum, I get the correct response, but no cookie is set. Just like that, no errors. It doesn't matter if I am gonna use nuxt auth or just plain old axios call.

This is what I have:

DOMAINS: API - publisher.local:8080; frontend - publisher.local:3000

NUXT AUTH CONFIG

```js
auth: {
    strategies: {
      laravelSanctum: {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'http://publisher.local:8080',
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/api/v1/login', method: 'post' },
          // logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
          // user: { url: '/auth/user', method: 'get' }
        }
      },
    },
  },
```

AXIOS CONFIG

```js
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://publisher.local:8080/api/v1', // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
    credentials: true,
    proxy: true,
  },
```

sanctum.php

```php
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,local:3000',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
```

session.php

```php
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.local'),
```

I tried different combinations and variations of these settings and none of it works. Do you guys have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Is the cookie being returned? It could be that you are getting a cookie but it’s not being set.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I said I do get the correct response but sadly for some reason cookie is not set.

Comment: Yeh I’m having the same issue. I still haven’t been able to figure it out. From what I can tell online, apparently it’s something to do with the origin and the request not coming from the same domain as the backend. But again, I haven’t been able to figure it out yet

Comment: I have the same suspicion. I will let you know when I get the answers.

Comment: Legend thanks. I have a few other things I’ll try after work and will let you know if I figure it out. Cheers

Comment: @Savlon just found out that .local cannot be a top level domain which is a requirement for this to work. I will try that out tomorrow. But you can try something like api.myapp.com and my app.com locally and see if it works. I will give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: well that may explain it then. I am also using .local so I’ll check it out, thanks man

Comment: I tried changing all of that to localhost and now I have that damn cookie before hitting the endpoint, so I am not sure if that is good either! I don't know where is it coming from.

Comment: haha ok well I’ll be sure to change mine! Thanks mate

Comment: I solved the issue and I will post answer later in the day or tomorrow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out I think. I got it to work.

So there are`.local` cannot be the top-level domain and that I think was perhaps part of the problem but I am not sure.

Changing domains to just pain old `localhost` did the trick but this solution had one issue. It will for some unknown to me reason I would automatically get an XSRF cookie on any call to my API, regardless of which endpoint I would call. Weird.

What worked perfectly was changing the domains to `api.publisher.com` and `publisher.com`, followed by all the settings from the Sanctum docs.

Just be super careful with the domains and make sure they match and that the settings are correct. It is super easy to reconfigure that thing and very hard to diagnose it!

Hope that helps!